# How does ArcGIS Pro 1.0 choose default color for first layer added to Map?

Tags: layers, color, arcgis-pro

When I add my first vector dataset to the Map in an ArcGIS Pro 1.0 project that I created using the Map.aptx project template, it always comes in using a gaudy brown color like in the graphic below.

[image]

Doing the "equivalent" in a Blank Map of ArcMap seems to choose a random pastel color which is much more pleasant to look at.

How does ArcGIS Pro 1.0 choose the first color to apply?  Perhaps it can be configured to something more pleasant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a known issue in first releases of Pro, and IIRC the team responsible fixed it in the latest (1.1) release.