# How does ArcGIS choose colors when adding layers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, color

Adding new map-able layers to a project automatically assigns a color. I haven't yet figured out according to which criteria or setting ArcMap choose which color to select - to me they appear to be always different and somewhat random.
So I'm curious if anyone knows where this is defined and how it can be manually set.

I found [this related post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151888/how-does-arcgis-pro-1-0-choose-default-color-for-first-layer-added-to-map) which hints that it might be defined through a [color scheme](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/symbols-and-styles/color-schemes.htm) - maybe even a [random one](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/symbols-and-styles/color-schemes.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_1928FD58215B49EA8F86382E6B3A1EE3)?

---

**Tl;dr:** Does someone definitely know

- which color scheme does ArcGIS 10 use by default
- where can I change this setting

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for default color schemes used when opening files in ArcMap they can be changed here.

[image]